# Calculate from 3 select box

Tags: jquery

I have 3 select box, and I want this equation.
( (Select2 - Select1) * 40000 ) + Select3

But it doesn't work very well :(

Here's my code HTML / Jquery.

```
 <select name="select1">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="1">2</option>
     <option value="1">3</option>
     <option value="1">4</option>
     <option value="1">5</option>
 </select>

 <select name="select2">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="1">2</option>
     <option value="1">3</option>
     <option value="1">4</option>
     <option value="1">5</option>
 </select>

 <select name="select3">
     <option value="1">10000</option>
     <option value="1">20000</option>
     <option value="1">30000</option>
     <option value="1">40000</option>
     <option value="1">50000</option>
 </select>

 <label id="total"></label>
```

**Jquery**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

      $('select').on('change', function() {

        $('#total').text(

          ( ($('select[name=select2]').val() - $('select[name=select1]').val() ) * 40000 )
           + $('select[name=select3]').val() 
        );

      });
```

Comment: All your options are having the value *1* which you are accessing via `.val()`

Comment: And for the future: `But it doesn't work very well` is never a good description of the problem you are having

Comment: @empiric You're right. It's all because of my English skill. I can't describe my problem as I want to. Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parseInt() function

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('select').on('change', function() {

    $('#total').text(

      ( parseInt(($('select[name="select2"]').val()) - parseInt($('select[name="select1"]').val()) ) * 40000 )
       + parseInt($('select[name="select3"]').val()) 
    );

  });
});
```

Don't forget to change value in value attributes

```
<select name="select1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select name="select2">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select name="select3">
    <option value="10000">10000</option>
    <option value="20000">20000</option>
    <option value="30000">30000</option>
    <option value="40000">40000</option>
    <option value="50000">50000</option>
</select>

Total: <label id="total">0</label>
```

Comment: Thanks, Rendi. It's really helpful. :) I want to ask you just one question. If I selected option in first select box, "Nan" is shown in #total. How can I set the total as 0 until every select box will be selected?

Comment: You mean default value is 0? So, put 0 in your total label like this <label id="total">0</label>

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have forgotten to change the `value` attribute that `.val()` is tied to.  Additionally, I made a function to make getting the value from the name and converting it to an int easier.  And I added `.trigger('change')`, so we can see the results on page load.

```js
function valByNameToInt(name) {
  return parseInt($('select[name="' + name + '"]').val());
}

$('select').on('change', function() {
  $('#total').text(
    (valByNameToInt('select1') - valByNameToInt('select2')) * 40000 + valByNameToInt('select3')
  );

}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
 </select>

 <select name="select2">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
 </select>

 <select name="select3">
     <option value="10000">10000</option>
     <option value="20000">20000</option>
     <option value="30000">30000</option>
     <option value="40000">40000</option>
     <option value="50000">50000</option>
 </select>

 <label id="total"></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {

      var res = (parseInt($('select[name=select2]').val()) -
          parseInt($('select[name=select1]').val()))        *
        40000
      parseInt($('select[name=select3]').val());


        $('#total').html(
          res

        );
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
 </select>

<select name="select2">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
 </select>

<select name="select3">
     <option value="10000">10000</option>
     <option value="20000">20000</option>
     <option value="30000">30000</option>
     <option value="40000">40000</option>
     <option value="50000">50000</option>
 </select>

<label id="total"></label>
```

You need parseInt (or parseFloat) to get mathematical result, like

```
parseInt(('select[name=select2]').val())
```

Comment: See running script

Answer (score 1):

All ur `option` values are 1 .Change that to get desired o/p

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $('select').on('change', function() {
  var a=parseInt( $('select[name=select1]').val());
  var b=parseInt( $('select[name=select2]').val());
  var c=parseInt( $('select[name=select3]').val());
  
  var total=((b-a)*4000)+c;
  
  $('#total').text(total);
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
 </select>

 <select name="select2">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
 </select>

 <select name="select3">
     <option value="10000">10000</option>
     <option value="20000">20000</option>
     <option value="30000">30000</option>
     <option value="40000">40000</option>
     <option value="50000">50000</option>
 </select>

 <label id="total"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should use the parseInt method, as you are addition and subtraction, which are commonly interpreted as concatenation operator rather than addition.

```
( parseInt($('select[name=select2]').val()) - parseInt($('select[name=select1]').val()) ) * 40000 ) + parseInt($('select[name=select3]').val())
```